# check is parameter is available in URI

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

```
http://xxxxxxxxx:8000/compare/387552/1/389688/1/success
```

I need to check if this URI has the `success` parameter. How can I do this preferably with javascript. The success parameter is optional.

pseudo code

```
if has success parameter in URI:
   do A

else:
   do B
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Look into basic javascript string operations. You should find you answer there

Comment: downvoter, is always nice downvote and go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = window.location.href;
var a = str.indexOf('success');

if(a >= 0){
  // means success exists
}else{
 // means success don't exists
}
```

Comment: Let's just hope that the domain isn't "get-successful.com".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex of `/\/success(\/|$)/` to test this:

```
if (/\/success(\/|$)/.test(window.location.href)) {
    console.log('Yep, it has success');
} else {
    console.log('Nope - no success');
}
```

This will accept `/success/` anywhere in the string and would match:

```
http://xxxxxxxxx:8000/compare/387552/1/389688/1/success
http://xxxxxxxxx:8000/compare/387552/1/389688/success/1
http://xxxxxxxxx:8000/compare/387552/1/success/389688/1
http://xxxxxxxxx:8000/compare/success/387552/1/389688/1
http://xxxxxxxxx:8000/success/compare/387552/1/389688/1
```

If you only want to match success and the **end** of the URL, you should use `/\/success\/?$/`:

```
if (/\/success\/?$/.test(window.location.href)) {
    console.log('Yep, it has success');
} else {
    console.log('Nope - no success');
}
```

Which will only match:

```
http://xxxxxxxxx:8000/compare/387552/1/389688/1/success
http://xxxxxxxxx:8000/compare/387552/1/389688/1/success/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Javascript function **indexof**

```
var url="http://xxxxxxxxx:8000/compare/387552/1/389688/1/success";
if(url.indexOf("success") > -1== true)
{
alert("present");
}
else
{
alert("not present");
}
```

That's all .